Estimating the value of cosine with its power series
In Amann's Analysis, the following is stated:

Here $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ denotes $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.
Corollary $II.7.9$ is the following


Here $s_n$ denotes the $n$th partial sum and $s$ the value of the series.
I have trouble seeing how corollary 7.9 shows the inequalities
$$1-\frac{t^2}{2} < \cos t < 1- \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^4}{24}.$$ Corollary 7.9 is about approximating the value of an alternating and decreasing series, but the absolute value of cosine series is not necessarily decreasing if $t>1$.

Your criticism is justified. The statement is true for all $t\neq0$ but corollary 7.9 only proves it for a limited range of $t,$ for example $|t|<1.$ The full statement is more easily deduced from the mean-value form of Taylor's theorem.

When $n>t$ the series start to decrease.  Whatever $t$ we choose, eventually $n$ will be large enough to force it to start decreasing -- and we only need the tail to be decreasing to apply our convergence rules.

@user317176 It is only true for convergence, not the error estimation.

Are you able to use 7.8 and 7.9 to convince yourself that the sequence of partial sums of odd many terms are (non-strictly) decreasing upper bounds for the convergent and the sequence of partial sums of even many terms are (non-strictly) increasing lower bounds for the convergent?

In case you're interested in an elementary approach you can start with the fact that $\cos x \le 1$ for all $x$. You may as well assume $t > 0$ since all functions in the inequality you want are even. Then
$$\int_0^t \cos x \, dx \le \int_0^t 1 \, dx$$ which works out to $\sin t \le t$. It follows that
$$\int_0^t \sin x \, dx \le \int_0^t x \, dx$$ which works out to $1 - \cos t \le \dfrac{t^2}{2}$, or in other words $1 - \dfrac{t^2}{2} \le \cos t$.
Two more iterations of this process yield $t - \dfrac{t^3}{6} \le \sin t$ and finally $\cos t \le 1 - \dfrac{t^2}{2} + \dfrac{t^4}{24}$.

I think you are effectively proving the mean-value version of Taylor's theorem.

It is correct that the terms of the cosine series are not decreasing in absolute value for arbitrary $t > 1$, but it can be easily seen that they are – apart from the constant term – decreasing in absolute value in a range which contains the value $\pi/2$.
For $0 < t < \sqrt{12} \approx 3.464$ is the sequence
$$
 \left( \frac{t^{2n}}{{(2n)}!}\right)_{n \ge 1}
$$
strictly decreasing, so that the partial sums of the alternating series
$$
 \left( \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{t^{2k}}{{(2k)}!}\right)_{n \ge 1}
$$
are less than $\cos(t)$ for odd $n \ge 1$, and greater than $\cos(t)$ for even $n \ge 2$.
In particular is
$$
 \cos(2) < 1 - \frac{2^2}{2!} +  \frac{2^4}{4!} = -\frac 13 < 0 \, .
$$
so that $\pi/2 < 2 < \sqrt{12}$.
It follows that the partial sums of the $\cos(\pi/2)$ series are less than $0$ for odd $n \ge 1$, and greater than $0$ for even $n \ge 2$, i.e. for $t_0 = \pi/2$ is
$$
1 - \frac{t_0^2}{2!} < 0 < 1 - \frac{t_0^2}{2!} +  \frac{t_0^4}{4!} \\
1 - \frac{t_0^2}{2!}  +  \frac{t_0^4}{4!} -  \frac{t_0^6}{6!}< 0 < 1 - \frac{t_0^2}{2!} +  \frac{t_0^4}{4!} -  \frac{t_0^6}{6!}+  \frac{t_0^8}{8!}
$$
and so on.
Some numerical calculations: Let $x_n$ denote the smallest positive zero of the partical sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{t^{2k}}{{(2k)}!}$. Then $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$ are alternatingly less than and greater than $\pi/2$. With PARI/GP I computed the following values for $2x_n$ (rounded to 10 decimal places):
$$\begin{array}{c|c} 
 n & 2x_n \\ \hline
1 & 2.8284271247 \\
2 & 3.1849008681 \\
3 & 3.1398116503 \\
4 & 3.1416421359 \\
5 & 3.1415917241 \\
6 & 3.1415926662
\end{array}$$

The series for
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}2\\&=\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}\mp\dots
\end{align}
is alternating, starts with a positive term and the absolute values of the terms are falling if it is the case for the first two, that is, if
$$
x^2<30.
$$
Clearly, the point under discussion falls comfortably inside the admissible interval.
The enclosure by the empty and first partial sum gives the claimed inequalities
$$
0<f(x)<\frac{x^4}{4!}.
$$
